# How to reset default interface of VLC?

Tags: vlc

I was playing with VLC skins downloaded from gnome-look.org. And now,I think, My VLC is bricked. It shows this error message on terminal:

`[0x1b15f08] skins2 interface error: no skins found : exiting`.

I don't wanna reinstall it either.

~$ vlc

```
VLC media player 2.0.8 Twoflower (revision 2.0.8a-0-g68cf50b)  
[0xd6df08] skins2 interface error: no XML found in theme /home/amol/Download/AlienWareVLCInvader.zip  
[0x7ff4e801d8f8] xml xml reader error: XML parser error (line 1) : Document is empty  
[0xd6df08] skins2 interface error: no skins found : exiting
```

please help...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

May I suggest you go to the [Ubuntu Software Center](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_Software_Center) (or [Synaptic Package Manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synaptic_%28software%29) if you prefer), search for VLC, and completely uninstall it? Then reinstall it. This will take less than five minutes, and is easier than editing the VLC configuration files.

If you won't uninstall/reinstall VLC, then open a terminal emulation window, do

```
rm ~/.config/vlc/vlcrc
```

and close the window.

Then, reopen VLC.

Comment: I don't wanna reinstall it.Isn't there any command or something which lets me reset VLC??

Comment: are you suggesting me to fully uninstall VLC?

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work...

Answer (score 8):

The command you are after is:

```
vlc --reset-config --reset-plugins-cache
```

Run this from a Terminal window and this will reset vlc to its installation defaults...

Answer (score 2):

I you need to change the skin of vlc, after copying files to /.local/share/vlc/skins2 simply go to preference and click at use custom skins.Then simply save and restart vlc.you do not need to choose any folder,when vlc will restart you will see that now skin is changed.Also you can change to other skins by going to change skins options in menu now.